# Blazor WASM - OpenIdConnect - Disable token validation to identity provider on every page refresh

Tags: authentication, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

We are creating a Blazor WASM application for usage on unstable and possibly slow connections. We have successfully implemented authentication with OpenIdConnect.

We noticed that on every refresh (F5) of the page, the token is being validated against the Identity Provider again:
[image: Calls to Identity Provider]

We think this is normal/desired behaviour, but is there any way around this?
We know this is a tiny amount of data, but it would be optimal to not have this every time.

The websites are for 'internal' usage only (through a VPN).

Thank you

Comment: I've been sitting with the same thing, but unfortunately, each refresh is a new instance of the WASM application. I've not found another way around it yet. Hoping this gets improved in future releases.

Comment: I can say though, a custom authenticator could make this work. if you are willing. You will probably need to use cookies for that and your API can do the rest.

Comment: @Marius Thank you for the feedback, seems like that is probably our only option. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have personally run into this issue as well. For us, it was even worse since the IdP would take quite some time since the **authorization** endpoint would ignore the `prompt=none` parameter and try to challenge the user every time Blazor WASM Authentication tried to refresh its authentication state. This forced me to do some digging so hopefully, my findings are useful to you.

The OIDC in Blazor WASM makes use of their [RemoteAuthenticationService](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/Services/RemoteAuthenticationService.cs) class which implements the `AuthenticationStateProvider` to provide an authentication state to Blazor WASM **on top** of the Access Token.

I think this is the key problem here. That they are separating the AuthState and AccessToken which (at least for me) was unintuitive since in the past I would determine whether a user is "logged in", purely based on if they have a valid access token or not.

So the fact that you already have an "AccessToken" is irrelevant to the AuthState which begs the question: How do they determine your AuthState?

Lets checkout this key function in the [RemoteAuthenticationService](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/Services/RemoteAuthenticationService.cs):

```
...

public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() => new AuthenticationState(await GetUser(useCache: true));

...

private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> GetUser(bool useCache = false)
{
    var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    if (useCache && now < _userLastCheck + _userCacheRefreshInterval)
    {
        return _cachedUser;
    }

    _cachedUser = await GetAuthenticatedUser();
    _userLastCheck = now;

    return _cachedUser;
}
```

In the above code snippet you can see that the AuthState is determined by this `GetUser` function which first checks some cache for the user which is currently hardcoded to expire every 60 seconds. This means that if you check the user's AuthState, then every 60 seconds it would have to query the IdP to determine the AuthState. This is how it does that:

1. Uses JSInterop to call `trySilentSignIn` on the [oidc-client](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts) typescript library.
2. SilentSignIn opens a hidden iframe to the IdP authorization endpoint to see if you are in fact signed in at the IdP. If successful then it reports the signed-in user to the AuthState provider.

The problem here is that this could happen every time you refresh the page or even every 60 seconds whenever you query the current AuthState where the user cache is expired. There is no persistence of the access token or the AuthState in any way.

**Ok so then how do I fix this?**

The only way I can think of is to implement your own `RemoteAuthenticationService` with some slight modifications from the one in the Authentication Library.

Specifically to

1. Potentially persist the access token.
2. Reimplement the getUser call to check the validity/presence of the persisted access token to get the user rather than using the silentSignin function on the oidc-client library.