In Blazor WASM with with Open ID Connect how can you force an Auth/ID Token refresh
I have a Blazor WASM app integrated with my IdP via Open ID Connect. We need custom claims that are stored in the ID Token and Auth Token. This all works fine in the most part. However, there are a couple of expected situations where a particular process will update source data for these and so the data in the tokens has become stale. So in the app I would like to force the refreshing of these tokens from the IdP so they have the latest information.
I have tried, unsuccessfully, to find how to so this. However, my Google-fu must be off as I have not found anything that even points me in the right direction.
If it is relevant I am using .Net 8 and my IdP is Auth0.
Anyone have any pointers?

Unfortunately not an expert in Open ID Connect, but aren't refresh tokens used for that in the Open ID Connect flow?

This little hacking may meet your requirement. You just need to clear the below session storage and login again. And the refresh login won't let user input name and password again. Because the Auth0 session doesn't really end.

You could try following sample.
Create a WASM standalone project add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
Create MyScript.js in wwwroot folder
function remove_session(prefix) {

    for (let i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = sessionStorage.key(i);

        if (key.startsWith(prefix)) {
            sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }
}

Index.cshtml add following (The package need this js interop)
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>

program.cs
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
   
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://xxx.auth0.com"; 
    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "xxx";           
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";           
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("profile");
    //options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("offline_access");   this will give you a refreshToken, but this sample doesn't need
    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:7056/authentication/login-callback";
    options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:7056/authentication/logout-callback";  
});

Add Authentication.razor
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action"></RemoteAuthenticatorView>
@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }
}

Home.razor
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject IJSRuntime js
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <p>Welcome, @context.User.Identity.Name</p>
        <button @onclick="RefreshAuth">Refresh</button>
        <button @onclick="Logout">Logout</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <button @onclick="Login">Login</button>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

    private async void Login()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/login");
    }

    private async Task Logout()
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }

    private async Task RefreshAuth()
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("remove_session","oidc");
        Login();        

    }
}

Test: click "login" to show userName. Then you change the username in Auth0 management console. Click refresh, the username will change to new one.
Besides, if you use refresh token. you could use  the IAccessTokenProvider to get new accessToken/IdToken which contains the new user information.
        var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(new AccessTokenRequestOptions
            {
                Scopes = new[] { "abc" }, // just use a scope that doesn't exist
            });

But the problem is AuthenticationStateProvider will use RemoteAuthenticationService in WASM. It uses jsinterop AuthenticationService.getUser() to fetch user principal. But this javascript function couldn't get you the new user from IdToken. I think something need to be fix here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75472254/20240963

Thanks. Will this force the user to have to sign in again? Or is this seamless?
